# Map a new directory to a remote git project branch

Tags: git, github

I have a project I've been working on with the repo stored on Github. I ran into issues upgrading packages, and instead of starting a new branch in the main local directory, I created a new directory and started with clean packages, and simply copied my project files into the new directory where everything now works.

For clarity I'll call the two directories `main` and `clean`.

I want to basically abandon the existing `main` directory and continue working on the `clean` directory-- but I need to make this new directory into a branch of the existing repo on Github.

Is it possible to create a git repo in my new `clean` directory, and make it correspond to a new branch of the actual repo on Github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be simpler than expected.

I went to `clean`, executed `git init`, then set the remote:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

I was now on branch `master` since I'd just initiated the repo. So I ran

```
git checkout -b mynewbranch
```

Then just `git add .` then `git commit -m "mymessage"` followed by a push to the upstream: `git push origin mynewbranch` and I was done.